# REST API Testing best strategy

Tags: unit-testing, testing, rest, django

I'm currently developing a personal project using Django REST + React and as it grows more complex, I want to add unit testing to ensure that changes don't affect previous functionality. However, I'm not sure exactly what to test for. Should I simply test the responses from the API endpoints, should I try random input to check if it's validated properly, should I try getting access or changing data that belong to a different user? What is the best strategy to ensure that a REST API is both stable and secure through testing?

Comment: Please: if you're going to downvote the question at least tell me why or suggest a different community. Thank you.

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: I'm clearly suggesting some tactics. It's a question can help people that are looking for ways to make better software, I can't understand the negativity...

Comment: Every method or function you write has a set of requirements associated with it; REST endpoints are no exception.  Write tests that prove the requirements are met.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What tests are appropriate for a REST backend code?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/359150/what-tests-are-appropriate-for-a-rest-backend-code)

Comment: This answers what to test for Spring specifically, not how to test.

Comment: "How to test" is a very broad topic. Ask yourself this, what does your application do? What are the last few issues that you had to resolve?

Comment: Spring Boot is mentioned in that post only in passing.  The post itself is good general advice.

Answer (score 1):

First you should distinguish the different kinds of tests. Each kind most likely requires a different test plan, test schedule, tester resources.

#### Unit tests

These don't test the API but internal functionality. You just need them. Like the next category, they should be automated, but triggered by developers to ensure that newly written code works as desired and code changes didn't break anything.

#### Function and regression tests

These correspond closely to unit tests and are basically black box tests as they don't care how the software is implemented. They should be deterministic, automated, cover all cases as specified in the API if possible. This includes tests for border conditions such as range checks, data format checks, as well as checks that error replies are as specified. Regression tests should be added for cases which weren't considered first but were discovered during use.

Automation is key! No version of the software should be released without having passed all tests, so they should be part of the build/CI pipeline (in addition to the unit tests which should also be run for any build).

#### Penetration tests and fuzzing

These tests can only be meaningfully performed by human testers with some insight into the code and historic failures to know where weaknesses may be found. Such tests require good analytic skills to determine how uncovered weaknesses can be further exploited.

You may be able to automate the initial stage by fuzzing to find input data which causes unexpected behavior (http status codes in the 500 range) indicating some internal error, but the following stages most likely can't be automated.

Comment: What do unit tests actually test in this case? The API is mostly, well, API endpoints, especially in Django REST that makes this stupidly easy to setup.